# C# dictionary equality requirement

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary, set, equality

Do the keys of a `Dictionary` need to be comparable with equality?

For example

```
Class mytype
{
    public bool equals(mytype other)
    {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

In my case they won't be equal unless they are the same instance.

If I need to implement equality should I have a large numeric value that increments with every new instance of `mytype` created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your classes are only `equal` if they are same instance, then you don't need to do anything to use them in a `Dictionary`. Classes (reference types) are considered equal if and only if the refer to the same object.

[From the documentation of GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx)

**For derived classes of Object, the GetHashCode method can delegate to the Object.GetHashCode implementation, if and only if that derived class defines value equality to be reference equality and the type is not a value type.**

Which seems to be true in your case.  As a rule of thumb, if you override **Equal** you need to override **GetHashCode** as well but this is not necessary in your case as the default is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

By default, equality is based on the instance. Two separate instances are never equal. You can only change that by providing your own Equals method.

Comment: you'd also want to implement `GetHashCode()`

Answer (score 2):

Only if they are being used as a key and you don't want to base equivalence on the instance of the object itself.  If you only want references to the exact same instance to be equivalent, you are fine and need do nothing, but if you are using your type as a key, and you want "equivalent" instances to be considered equal, your class must implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`.

If your custom type is being stored as a value, and not used as a key, this is not necessary, of course.  For example, in this case MyType does not need to override `Equals()` or `GetHashCode()` because it is only used as a value, and not as the storage key.

```
Dictionary<string, MyType> x;
```

However in this case:

```
Dictionary<MyType, string> x;
```

Your custom type is the key, and thus it would need to override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`.  The `GetHashCode()` is used to determine which location it hashes to, and the `Equals()` is used to resolve collisions on the hash code (among other things).

You'd need to override the same two methods when dealing with many `LINQ` queries as well.  Alternatively, you can provide a standalone `IEqualityComparer` apart from your class to determine if two instances are equivalent.

Comment: But if reference equality is the desired behavior, the type should not override these methods, and the OP seems to indicate that reference equality *is* the desired behavior.

Comment: @phoog: good question, his statement "In my case they won't be equal unless they are the same instance" to me can be read either way as in "this is what it's doing" or "this is what I want it to do", I updated my answer to reflect either way.

Answer (score 1):

See the [EqualityComparer.Default<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx) property. This is how the dictionary obtains an equality comparer if you don't supply it with one.

This returns an equality comparer based on the type & capabilities of T.

For example, if T extends IEquatable, EqualityComparer.Default will return an equality comparer instance that uses the IEquatable interface. Otherwise it will return an equality comparer instance that uses the Object.Equals method.

The Object.Equals method, by default for reference types, uses reference equality (Object.ReferenceEquals) unless you override it with a custom comparison.

The Object.Equals method, by default for value types, uses reflection to compare the fields of the struct for equality*. Reflection being slow, this is why it's always recommended to override Equals in value types.

* unless it's a blittable value type in which case the raw bits are compared.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no type constraints on `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`